# IOS Swift Alamofire.request post to php form

Tags: ios, swift, contact-form, alamofire

Just beginning development here, I've been working to convert a html form to IOS Swift and need a bit of guidance. I'm using Alamofire and am unsure how to tie the submit button and the UITextlabels to the .POST request. Appreciate any assistance you can offer. I've been searching for some time without much luck.  Thanks!

PHP fields on server:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

Swift code:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class formViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailText: UITextField!

    @IBAction func submitButton(sender: UIButton) {

        let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [:] // fill in your params
        let request = Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://testserver.com/form.php", parameters: parameters)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you're unsure of how to access the data from the UITextField and append it to your array, correct?

Comment: @jkaufman Yes, that is correct. I presume I need to append the fields to the array and then pass the values to the server with .POST. Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: Well, first off, let's first test your PHP script. Typically, I always tell people to test their scripts first, so if you do receive an error, you know where it is. To test your PHP script, you can download [Postman](https://getpostman.com), a Chrome extension. Verify that your script works as you want and then return here.

Comment: @jkaufman yes, the php script works fine and I am receiving data from my html form.

Comment: Do you know how to access the UITextField's data? (Hint: it's using dot notation.) If you don't, I then have enough information for a final answer.

Comment: @jkaufman I've used self.view.addSubview(myTextField) in the past to add to myViewControllers. Just at a loss and appreciate your help.  Starting to think that using Objective C might be the way to go as the Swift documentation and examples here seem to be limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIKit` is a very strong API, and hence, accessing the data from a `UITextField` is as easy as doing `myTextField.text`. Note that this will still return a string value even if it is blank, so it would be best to check to see if it has an actual value. Since you've used Interface Builder, it's even easier to access your values. For example:

```
let array: [String: String] = ["name": nameText.text]
```

As for your comment on switching to Objective-C:
Although switching to Objective-C might have advantages on some levels, I would say if you just plan to switch over due to a lack of tutorials and documentation, don't. Learn Objective-C, and converting between the two languages will become a skill that's natural. Hence, even if there is no documentation for Swift, you'll still be able to accomplish it as you can simply convert the Objective-C code. And as for the small difference such as optionals and AnyObject, these are well documented not only by Apple but also many parts of the internet (i.e. SO and Ray Wenderlich).

Comment: Naming your dictionary "array" is just mean.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to complete my post request without Alamofire. Here's what is working for me at the moment. Feel free to offer any suggestions for improvement. Appreciate the assistance.

```
func postToServerFunction() {

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://testserver.com/test.php")!
        var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)

        let bodyData = "firstName=" + firstName.text + "&lastName=" + lastName.text + "&phoneNumber=" + phoneNumber.text

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) ...
```

Comment: Were you unable to populate the parameters dictionary the same way you constructed the bodyData string? Why would that be?

Comment: @rikkigibson yeah Rikki, I was able to get this working using `let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = ["firstName" : firstName.text]`  Thanks man.